# User authentication using django-oauth-toolkit

Tags: python, django, oauth, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I am new to OAuth and Django Rest Framework. I have created a user model in django, now I want to use it on my native mobile application. So, how do i create authentication using OAuth. What flow should I use? Do i need to create a client application for every user? 
Please help me with it or provide a nice tutorial. I have read the documentation of django-oauth-toolkit. I have understood the basics, but did not understand the implementation.

Comment: Did you find any good tutorial @rishabsaraf93

Answer (score 2):

Follow official django oauth toolkit docs [Click Here](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Install with pip

```
pip install django-oauth-toolkit
```

Add oauth2_provider to your INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'oauth2_provider',
)
```

If you need an OAuth2 provider you’ll want to add the following to your urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
]
```

then Create an OAuth2 Client Application
by using client_id and client_secret